# Android font size difference issue on gingerbread and jellybeans

Tags: android, layout, font-size

Emulator/Device Specs:

**HDPI**

**RESOLUTION** 1280 x 800

**SCREEN SIZE** 5.3

Following two images are captured from two emulators with specs mentioned above. Both emulators have everything same except OS version

[image] **ANDROID** 2.3.5 (Gingerbread)

[image] **ANDROID** 4.1.1 (Jelly Bean)

I have used a custom background image for EditText.
For EditText **android:textAppearance** property is set to **70sp** for both emulators.

So, my question is why on Jelly Beans text size is bigger than text size on gingerbread?

Note: This issue is also seen on ICS.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

This is what i am getting now after making the EditText background image nine-patch.
The text is not fit inside the EditText

Following are the EditText properties in XML.

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone_number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="28dip"
        android:background="@drawable/lcdscreen_no_glow"
        android:singleLine="true" 
        android:maxLength="12"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:textAppearance="@style/EditTextStyleMedium"      
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have used a custom background image for EditText

That background image should be a nine-patch PNG file so that it can stretch accordingly.

> So, my question is why on Jelly Beans text size is bigger than text size on gingerbread?

If nothing else, the default font is different. Android 1.x/2.x used the Droid font family, while Android 4.x uses Ruboto. Since, by eyeball, the heights appear the same, the Ruboto glyphs for `9` are apparently wider.

Comment: Thanks. So what you suggest? Change the font size at runtime?

Comment: @MA1: I suggest having a stretchable background.

Comment: @MA1: Since your width is `fill_parent`, make the parent bigger. Or, make your font size be a dimension resource and have versions of that resource in `res/values/` and `res/values-v14/` (the latter would be used for Android 4.0+).