# Android jelly bean text view with custom font ,not fitting

Tags: android, textview, android-4.2-jelly-bean, bounds

Just for the info ,I have gone all the resources that tells how to fit text within bounds

1. [Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033012/auto-scale-textview-text-to-fit-within-bounds)
2. [How to scale/resize text to fit a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596452/how-to-scale-resize-text-to-fit-a-textview)
3. [How to adjust text font size to fit textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617266/how-to-adjust-text-font-size-to-fit-textview)
4. [Android font size difference issue on gingerbread and jellybeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010644/android-font-size-difference-issue-on-gingerbread-and-jellybeans)

But my main problem is that I don't want to resize the font to fit within text bounds.What I have is a `TextView` which takes a `Custom Font` from `assets` folder.Further the user is able to change the font size via `slider`.All the devices lower than `Jelly Bean` there seems no problem,but `Jelly Bean` devices the text doesn't fit the bounds of the `TextView` as shown in the image 
[image: textview not fitting]

Further neither of purposed solution as stated on `stackoverflow` answers do any good.Somehow some of the solution simply lowers down the `font` size to fit within bounds.
I do not want to lower font size,instead I want to do the following

1. Calculate the length of the text that fits on the width of the screen
2. Then append newline to the string at that particular length
3. Since the text length will be large,I am afraid to use StringBuffer and StringBuilder as they could easily result in `out of memory exception`
4. So the `TextView` automatically calculates the factor inserts news line when reaches the 
   visible length.

So far I am able to break down text,by calculating a factor which helps to find the minimum amount of words that fit on width of the screen.But ,this it results in words being broken meaning `Hello` can result into `Hel` in one line and other line continued by `lo`.

```
public class AutoResizeTextView extends TextView {

private boolean forFirstTime = true;

    @Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (forFirstTime)
        monitorChanges();
}



private void monitorChanges() {
    final int widthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft()
            - getCompoundPaddingRight();
    if (widthLimit <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    final String mainText = getText().toString();
    final float actualTextWidth = getPaint().measureText(mainText);

    forFirstTime = false;

    setText("");
    String[] overallText = inputText.split("\\n");

    for(int j=0;j<overallText.length;j++){
        String mainText =overallText[j];
        int length = mainText.length();
        int lineNumber = Math.round(getPaint().measureText(mainText)/ widthLimit);
        int wordLimit = (int) Math.round(length / (lineNumber * 1.3));
        //wordLimit+=2;
        if (wordLimit < length) {
            int count = Math.round(length / wordLimit);
            int startIndex = -1, endIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                startIndex = wordLimit * i;
                endIndex = wordLimit * (i + 1);
             append(mainText.substring(startIndex, endIndex) + "\n");
            }
        append(mainText.toString().substring(endIndex, length)+"\n");
        }
   }
}
```

Now I want the words not be broken,as exhibited by default android `EditText` on `wrap_content` params,where the whole text is moved to next line,if it becomes large to fit.
And further the formula for calculating the `wordLimit` is not accurate,I just want to find out the exact length of the `string` that fits the `widthLimit` of `TextView/EditText`

I am also working on it and if anything comes,I will surely post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know this is the right solution or not.But so far,text is rendered well and no text cut off i.e. text shown within bounds.

```
public class AutoResizeTextView extends TextView {


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (forFirstTime)
        monitorChanges();
}

private boolean forFirstTime = true;
    // Text view line spacing multiplier
    private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

    // Text view additional line spacing
    private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

private void monitorChanges() {
    int widthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft()
            - getCompoundPaddingRight();

    if (widthLimit <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    String inputText = getText().toString();

    forFirstTime = false;

    setText("");
    String[] overallText = inputText.split("\\n");

    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();
    for(int j=0;j<overallText.length;j++){
        String mainText =overallText[j];
        StaticLayout layout = new    StaticLayout(mainText,textPaint,widthLimit,Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                mSpacingMult,mSpacingAdd,false);        
        if(layout.getLineCount()>0){
            for(int i=0;i<layout.getLineCount();i++){
                int start =layout.getLineStart(i);
                int end =layout.getLineEnd(i);
                append(mainText.substring(start, end)+"\n");
            }
        }

    }   
}
}
```

But I am not completely satisfied with the result ;)